# Sql Server Performance issue with UNION

Tags: sql-server

### Is there any better way to write the below code

Here I am trying to get single row data into Multiple rows and column data

```
SELECT summary.MonNum,summary.Medical,summary.Surgical,summary.Affinity

FROM (
        SELECT '01' as MonNum, SUM(DISTINCT m.[ChangeXMon01Cases]) as Medical,
            SUM(DISTINCT s.[ChangeXMon01Cases]) as Surgical,
            SUM(DISTINCT a.IncrNet01Total) as Affinity
        FROM dbo.vwBaselineCurMonthMedCCMCC m,dbo.vwBaselineCurMonthSurgCCMCC 
            s,dbo.vwCurMonthAffinity a
        UNION SELECT '02' as MonNum, SUM(DISTINCT m.[ChangeXMon02Cases]) as 
            Medical,
            SUM(DISTINCT s.[ChangeXMon02Cases]) as Surgical,
            SUM(DISTINCT a.IncrNet02Total) as Affinity
        FROM dbo.vwBaselineCurMonthMedCCMCC m,dbo.vwBaselineCurMonthSurgCCMCC 
            s,dbo.vwCurMonthAffinity a
        UNION SELECT '03' as MonNum, SUM(DISTINCT m.[ChangeXMon03Cases]) as 
            Medical,
            SUM(DISTINCT s.[ChangeXMon03Cases]) as Surgical,
            SUM(DISTINCT a.IncrNet03Total) as Affinity
        FROM dbo.vwBaselineCurMonthMedCCMCC m,dbo.vwBaselineCurMonthSurgCCMCC 
            s,dbo.vwCurMonthAffinity a
        UNION SELECT '04' as MonNum,SUM(DISTINCT m.[ChangeXMon04Cases]) as 
            Medical,
            SUM(DISTINCT s.[ChangeXMon04Cases]) as Surgical,
            SUM(DISTINCT a.IncrNet04Total) as Affinity
        FROM dbo.vwBaselineCurMonthMedCCMCC m,dbo.vwBaselineCurMonthSurgCCMCC 
             s,dbo.vwCurMonthAffinity a
        UNION SELECT '05' as MonNum,SUM(DISTINCT m.[ChangeXMon05Cases]) as 
             Medical,
            SUM(DISTINCT s.[ChangeXMon05Cases]) as Surgical,
            SUM(DISTINCT a.IncrNet05Total) as Affinity 
        FROM dbo.vwBaselineCurMonthMedCCMCC m,dbo.vwBaselineCurMonthSurgCCMCC 
            s,dbo.vwCurMonthAffinity a
        UNION SELECT '06' as MonNum, SUM(DISTINCT m.[ChangeXMon06Cases]) as 
            Medical,
            SUM(DISTINCT s.[ChangeXMon06Cases]) as Surgical,
            SUM(DISTINCT a.IncrNet06Total) as Affinity
        FROM dbo.vwBaselineCurMonthMedCCMCC m,dbo.vwBaselineCurMonthSurgCCMCC 
            s,dbo.vwCurMonthAffinity a
        UNION SELECT '07' as MonNum, SUM(DISTINCT m.[ChangeXMon07Cases]) as 
            Medical,
            SUM(DISTINCT s.[ChangeXMon07Cases]) as Surgical,
            SUM(DISTINCT a.IncrNet07Total) as Affinity
        FROM dbo.vwBaselineCurMonthMedCCMCC m,dbo.vwBaselineCurMonthSurgCCMCC 
            s,dbo.vwCurMonthAffinity a
        UNION SELECT '08' as MonNum, SUM(DISTINCT m.[ChangeXCurMonCases]) as 
            Medical,
            SUM(DISTINCT s.[ChangeXCurMonCases]) as Surgical,
            SUM(DISTINCT a.IncrNet08Total) as Affinity
        FROM dbo.vwBaselineCurMonthMedCCMCC m,dbo.vwBaselineCurMonthSurgCCMCC 
            s,dbo.vwCurMonthAffinity a
        UNION SELECT '09' as MonNum, SUM(DISTINCT m.[ChangeXMon09Cases]) as 
            Medical,
            SUM(DISTINCT s.[ChangeXMon09Cases]) as Surgical,
            SUM(DISTINCT a.IncrNet09Total) as Affinity
        FROM dbo.vwBaselineCurMonthMedCCMCC m,dbo.vwBaselineCurMonthSurgCCMCC 
            s,dbo.vwCurMonthAffinity a
        UNION SELECT '10' as MonNum, SUM(DISTINCT m.[ChangeXMon10Cases]) as 
            Medical,
            SUM(DISTINCT s.[ChangeXMon10Cases]) as Surgical,
            SUM(DISTINCT a.IncrNet10Total) as Affinity
        FROM dbo.vwBaselineCurMonthMedCCMCC m,dbo.vwBaselineCurMonthSurgCCMCC 
            s,dbo.vwCurMonthAffinity a
        UNION SELECT '11' as MonNum, SUM(DISTINCT m.[ChangeXMon11Cases]) as 
            Medical,
            SUM(DISTINCT s.[ChangeXMon11Cases]) as Surgical,
            SUM(DISTINCT a.IncrNet11Total) as Affinity
        FROM dbo.vwBaselineCurMonthMedCCMCC m,dbo.vwBaselineCurMonthSurgCCMCC 
             s,dbo.vwCurMonthAffinity a
        UNION SELECT '12' as MonNum, SUM(DISTINCT m.[ChangeXMon12Cases]) as 
            Medical,
            SUM(DISTINCT s.[ChangeXMon12Cases]) as Surgical,
            SUM(DISTINCT a.IncrNet12Total) as Affinity
        FROM dbo.vwBaselineCurMonthMedCCMCC m,dbo.vwBaselineCurMonthSurgCCMCC 
            s,dbo.vwCurMonthAffinity a

) AS summary
```

output:

```
MonNum  Medical Surgical    Affinity
01  131098  -304054 -13094.400161
02  198305  -219429 158377.306254
03  327665  149538  8036.917062
04  121523  -80070  -54726.796843
05  158123  -38752  9148.561439
06  250181  -282588 46500.832405
07  116441  -110616 143473.396812
08  78575   -33361  -42891.408985
09    0        0    0.000000
10    0        0    0.000000
11    0        0    0.000000
12    0        0    0.000000
```

Comment: You do realise you are creating cartesian products with those implicit joins without join conditions? Fixing the joins and using `union all` will probably help performance.

Comment: Use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for more than 20 years.  Then probably it will fix your performance problem.